# How did the Tesseract get to Earth?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, captain-america

We are watching the whole Marvel Cinematic Universe in preparation for the new Avengers movie coming up in May. While watching *Captain America: The First Avenger*, I realized that it's never explained how the Tesseract came to be on Earth for Red Skull to find it in World War II. Did it come from Asgard when Jotunheim and Asgard fought on Earth?